# structure on the stack - fields initialized?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, automatic-storage

Consider the following code:

```
void func()
{
   int p;
   ...
   if (p > MAX) {
       struct my_struct s;
       ...
       /* here we access the contents 's' as '&s' */
   }
}
```

In this snippet `s` is on the stack. Is it guaranteed that the compiler initializes all structure fields to zero?

Comment: absolutely not. No automatic initialization is done for automatic storage in `c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a variable (`struct` or otherwise) is declared local to a function or a containing scope (i.e. has automatic storage duration), it is not initialized in any way.  You need to explicitly set the fields in the `struct`.

If you initialize at least one field of a struct but not all, then the remaining fields will be initialized the same as file scope variables (i.e. variables with static storage duration), which means `NULL` for pointer types and 0 for numeric types.

From section 6.7.9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *10* **If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.** If an object that
>   has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned)
>   zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized
>   (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
>   to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is
>   initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is
>   initialized to zero bits;
>
> ...
>
> *21* **If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate**, or fewer characters in
>   a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
>   are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
>   duration.**

Comment: "If you initialize at least one field of a struct but not all, then the remaining fields will be initialized to 0." -- is this guaranteed by the C standard?

Comment: @Mark 0 or equivalent, but mostly, yes,

Comment: @Mark Yes it is.  See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's quite the opposite.

Since `s` is an automatic storage local scoped (i.e., block scoped) variable, unless initialized explicitly, the contents are **indeterminate**.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. [...].

However, if you want to zero-initialize the variable for an(y) aggregate type, you can simply use an initialization statement like

> ```
> aggregate-type variable = {0};
> ```

which uses the following property from paragraph 21 of the same chapter, (*emphasis mine*)

> **If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate**, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

Answer (score 2):

No, they won't be initialized at all. The structure values will end up with whatever garbage is on the stack where the structure is placed.